# I am trying to view the definition of the stored procedure using sp_helptext but I am not able to. Can you please suggest?

Tags: sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMi8v.jpg)

I am trying to view the definition of the stored procedure using sp_helptext but I am not able to. Can you please suggest?

Comment: why are you using c# and asp.net tags when is strictly a sql-server question?

Answer (score 0):

use the following:-

USE MSDev
EXEC sp_helptext 'yourProcedureName'

Hope it helps.

Regards,